# Custom shapes in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

There are some shapes like different shirts and jeans design that I use quite frequently in my drawings in GIMP.

Does anyone know of a way with the help of which I can have a panel of my own custom designed shapes with the other shapes in GIMP's tool box?

I need this because then I will be able to draw a shirt, for example, simply the way we use other shapes provided by GIMP by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to create custom shapes but one can export different customized paths using the Path utility of GIMP and then import them whenever needed.

For more info refer to: http://www.scrapbooksgonedigital.com/Forum/showthread.php?t=874